# Rails / Heroku / Assets not being included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, assets

I have an application that uses redactor (a wysiwyg editor) it works perfectly locally, and it also works when I upload it, except the config file, which is located in a subfolder doesent do anything, when pushing to Heroku. I tried precompiling, using:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I have config.assets.enabled = false

The config.js file, that is not working on Heroku, is included in application.js as redactor-rails/config

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added config.js to your local git repository before pushing?

[Edit]

A couple more things to check. Are you using the redactor-rails gem, and if so, is it in your gemfile?

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'redactor-rails'
```

Is your gemfile.lock checked into git?

[Edit 2]

I've now tested this out, and indeed, there's an issue with redactor-rails, which causes custom config to be overwritten by the gem's default.

On the github repo, there is a solution, which I've tested on heroku, and copied here:

> `rails generate redactor:config` generates the file `app\assets\redactor-rails\config.js`.
>   This will not work in the asset pipeline correctly as the `rake assets:precompile` task
>   will still take `config.js` from the gem instead of the app (not that it'll work fine in 
>   development though). See [Overriding backend assets in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829726/overriding-backend-assets-in-production-environment)
>
> The solution is to create your own config.js (or any file name) and put it anywhere in your >app's assets. Then when requiring redactor, instead of `//= require redactor-rails`, use:

```
//= require redactor-rails/redactor.min
//= require path/to/custom/config
```

Works for me. Hope that helps. https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues/16

Comment: Works! - I forgot to re-compile using: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile. But after that it works.. awesome!

Comment: hi guys, did the same steps, but didn't work for me, using it on heroku, any ideas?

Comment: If you did the above and it didn't work -- be sure you're not using jQuery 1.9, which broke redactor for me. jquery-rails 2.2.0 packages jquery 1.9. Specify jquery-rails ~> 2.1.4 in your gemfile.